# Magento: Deleting multi store (sites) and cleaning up database

Tags: magento

Currently i have magento setup using multi sites (store views which go to other sites). I have around 7 stores setup in this way all running of a single backend and database. Over time its become very bulky, for instance my database weighs in at over 1GB and indexing is now a very lengthy process. So for obvious reasons i am now splitting these up into there own magento backend / database.

I have managed to do exactly that by duplicating my magento install and deleting the unecessary store views leaving the 1 store i want to keep. The problem of course is magento does not delete the database entries for these deleted stores so i still have a very bulky database with unecessary data.

So my question - How can i delete this left over data in my database ? I assume magento keeps some sort of id's to link the data to the store view so perhaps an sql query exists that i can run.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but the Logs in Magento was creating a huge DB for us (we run 37 stores on one install, 200K customer list and Huge inventory) we just turned off Logging in System >> Configuration >> Advanced >> Admin >> Admin Actions Logging. This reduced our Database by 2/3s after the archiving caught up. Is this still on for you? Seems a waste to run multiple installs.

Comment: I said Reduce by 2/3s meant to say reduced to 2/3s

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is getting bulky and thats the only reason you are going to split Magento from Multistore to single store I suggest you to rethink.

It appears that you have not set your cron as is required in Magento.
This is resulting in certain tables(log tables) not being cleaned at a regular time.
Also you need to configure log cleaning frequency.

After doing this first check your DB size.

Also:
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning  can be used.

or at Data base level :
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;

Comment: Thanks for the replies but i already have the cron set to run every 5 minutes. The logs get cleaned frequently but my database is still extremely bulky. With the logs we are talking maybe 5GB and without logs its just over 1GB. The problem is simply having too many multi site stores under one magento install as each store amounts to 20k products, countless customers and orders. I honestly think the only solution is to move each store to their own magento install.

Comment: Its more of your setup matter rather then Code issue.Very huge sites are running on Magento enterprise versions. Its suggested that you upgrade your setup. A different server for Mysql or rather two Mysql(Percona) servers for load balancing should do.